# Procedural world generation can't handle big maps

Tags: c#, performance, procedural-generation, procedural-programming, gridworld

so, I'm making a terraria-like game in unity 2019 on windws 10 using c# which has procedurally generated tilemaps and i have this script attached to a grid:

```
using UnityEngine;
using AccidentalNoise;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
using System;

public class CompileTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TileBase dirtTile;
    public TileBase grassTile;
    public TileBase stoneTile;

    public List<GameObject> fractalLayers = new List<GameObject>();

    public Tilemap grid;
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public float seed;
    public int caveSmoothness = 2;

    void Start()
    {
        grid.ClearAllTiles();

        int touchCount = 0;
        Vector3Int newPos;
        double nx, ny;

        ModuleBase combinedTerrain = CavesAndMountains((uint)seed);
        List<Vector3Int> terrainCoords = new List<Vector3Int>();
        SMappingRanges ranges = new SMappingRanges();

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                nx = (ranges.mapx0 + ((double)x / (double)width) * (ranges.mapx1 - ranges.mapx0)) * 3;
                ny = (ranges.mapy0 + ((double)y / (double)height) * (ranges.mapy1 - ranges.mapy0)) * 3;

                if (combinedTerrain.Get(nx, ny) > 0f)
                {
                    terrainCoords.Add(new Vector3Int(x, height - y, 0));
                }
            }
        }

        List<Tuple<int, int>> neighbors = new List<Tuple<int, int>>() {Tuple.Create(1, 1), Tuple.Create(-1, -1),
                                                                       Tuple.Create(0, 1), Tuple.Create(1, 0),
                                                                       Tuple.Create(0, -1), Tuple.Create(-1, 0),
                                                                       Tuple.Create(-1, 1), Tuple.Create(1, -1)};

        for (int index = 0; index < terrainCoords.Count; index++)
        {
            if (index == terrainCoords.Count)
            {
                break;
            }

            touchCount = 0;

            for (int posAdd = 0; posAdd < neighbors.Count; posAdd++)
            {
                newPos = new Vector3Int(terrainCoords[index].x + neighbors[posAdd].Item1, terrainCoords[index].y + neighbors[posAdd].Item2, 0);
                touchCount += terrainCoords.Contains(newPos) ? 1 : 0;
            }

            if (touchCount < 2)
            {
                terrainCoords.Remove(terrainCoords[index]);
            }

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < caveSmoothness; j++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    if (!terrainCoords.Contains(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0)))
                    {
                        touchCount = 0;

                        for (int posAdd = 0; posAdd < neighbors.Count; posAdd++)
                        {
                            newPos = new Vector3Int(x + neighbors[posAdd].Item1, y + neighbors[posAdd].Item2, 0);
                            touchCount += terrainCoords.Contains(newPos) ? 1 : -1;
                        }

                        if (touchCount > 1)
                        {
                            terrainCoords.Add(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0));
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
        }

        foreach (Vector3Int blck in terrainCoords)
        {
            grid.SetTile(blck, stoneTile);
        }

        terrainCoords.Sort((x, y) => x.x == y.x ? x.y.CompareTo(y.y) : x.x.CompareTo(y.x));
        terrainCoords.Reverse();

        TileBase selectedTile;
        int depth = 0;
        int lastx = 0;
        int lasty = terrainCoords[0].y + 1;

        foreach (Vector3Int blck in terrainCoords)
        {
            depth = blck.x != lastx ? 0 : depth;
            lasty = blck.x != lastx ? blck.y + 1 : lasty;

            selectedTile = depth < 4 ? grassTile : stoneTile;
            selectedTile = 3 < depth && depth < 30 ? dirtTile : selectedTile;

            grid.SetTile(blck, selectedTile);

            lastx = blck.x;
            depth += lasty - blck.y;
            lasty = blck.y;
        }

        int layerNum = 1;
        List<Vector3Int> posList = new List<Vector3Int>();

        foreach (GameObject layer in fractalLayers)
        {
            GetPerlinLayer component = layer.GetComponent<GetPerlinLayer>();

            for (int k = 0; k < component.populateCount; k++)
            {
                layerNum++;
                foreach (Vector3Int pos in component.GetFractalCoords(width, height, (uint)(seed * layerNum)))
                    if (grid.GetTile(pos) != null && grid.GetTile(pos) != grassTile)
                    {
                        grid.SetTile(pos, component.defaultTile);
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    public static ModuleBase CavesAndMountains(uint seed)
    {
        AccidentalNoise.Gradient ground_gradient = new AccidentalNoise.Gradient(0, 0, 0, 1);

        // lowlands
        Fractal lowland_shape_fractal = new Fractal(FractalType.BILLOW, BasisTypes.GRADIENT, InterpTypes.QUINTIC, 2, 0.25, seed);
        AutoCorrect lowland_autocorrect = new AutoCorrect(lowland_shape_fractal, 0, 1);
        ScaleOffset lowland_scale = new ScaleOffset(0.125, -0.45, lowland_autocorrect);
        ScaleDomain lowland_y_scale = new ScaleDomain(lowland_scale, null, 0);
        TranslatedDomain lowland_terrain = new TranslatedDomain(ground_gradient, null, lowland_y_scale);

        // highlands
        Fractal highland_shape_fractal = new Fractal(FractalType.FBM, BasisTypes.GRADIENT, InterpTypes.QUINTIC, 4, 2, seed);
        AutoCorrect highland_autocorrect = new AutoCorrect(highland_shape_fractal, -1, 1);
        ScaleOffset highland_scale = new ScaleOffset(0.25, 0, highland_autocorrect);
        ScaleDomain highland_y_scale = new ScaleDomain(highland_scale, null, 0);
        TranslatedDomain highland_terrain = new TranslatedDomain(ground_gradient, null, highland_y_scale);

        // mountains
        Fractal mountain_shape_fractal = new Fractal(FractalType.RIDGEDMULTI, BasisTypes.GRADIENT, InterpTypes.QUINTIC, 8, 1, seed);
        AutoCorrect mountain_autocorrect = new AutoCorrect(mountain_shape_fractal, -1, 1);
        ScaleOffset mountain_scale = new ScaleOffset(0.3, 0.15, mountain_autocorrect);
        ScaleDomain mountain_y_scale = new ScaleDomain(mountain_scale, null, 0.15);
        TranslatedDomain mountain_terrain = new TranslatedDomain(ground_gradient, null, mountain_y_scale);

        // terrain
        Fractal terrain_type_fractal = new Fractal(FractalType.FBM, BasisTypes.GRADIENT, InterpTypes.QUINTIC, 3, 0.125, seed);
        AutoCorrect terrain_autocorrect = new AutoCorrect(terrain_type_fractal, 0, 1);
        ScaleDomain terrain_type_y_scale = new ScaleDomain(terrain_autocorrect, null, 0);
        AccidentalNoise.Cache terrain_type_cache = new AccidentalNoise.Cache(terrain_type_y_scale);
        Select highland_mountain_select = new Select(terrain_type_cache, highland_terrain, mountain_terrain, 0.55, 0.2);
        Select highland_lowland_select = new Select(terrain_type_cache, lowland_terrain, highland_mountain_select, 0.25, 0.15);
        AccidentalNoise.Cache highland_lowland_select_cache = new AccidentalNoise.Cache(highland_lowland_select);
        Select ground_select = new Select(highland_lowland_select_cache, 0, 1, 0.5, null);

        // caves
        Fractal cave_shape = new Fractal(FractalType.RIDGEDMULTI, BasisTypes.GRADIENT, InterpTypes.QUINTIC, 1, 4, seed);
        Bias cave_attenuate_bias = new Bias(highland_lowland_select_cache, 0.65);
        Combiner cave_shape_attenuate = new Combiner(CombinerTypes.MULT, cave_shape, cave_attenuate_bias);
        Fractal cave_perturb_fractal = new Fractal(FractalType.FBM, BasisTypes.GRADIENT, InterpTypes.QUINTIC, 6, 3, seed);
        ScaleOffset cave_perturb_scale = new ScaleOffset(0.5, 0, cave_perturb_fractal);
        TranslatedDomain cave_perturb = new TranslatedDomain(cave_shape_attenuate, cave_perturb_scale, null);
        Select cave_select = new Select(cave_perturb, 1, 0, 0.75, 0);

        return new Combiner(CombinerTypes.MULT, cave_select, ground_select) as ModuleBase;
    }
}
```

which i have so graciously borrowed and modified from the fine folks at accidental noise, and i made an empty gameobject which i attached this script to:

```
using UnityEngine;
using AccidentalNoise;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class GetPerlinLayer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TileBase defaultTile;
    public float threshold = 0.5f;
    public int populateCount = 5;

    public List<Vector3Int> GetFractalCoords(int width, int height, uint seed)
    {
        double nx, ny;

        ModuleBase combinedTerrain = new Fractal(FractalType.FBM, BasisTypes.GRADIENT, InterpTypes.QUINTIC, 6, 2, seed);
        List<Vector3Int> fractalCoords = new List<Vector3Int>();
        SMappingRanges ranges = new SMappingRanges();

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                nx = (ranges.mapx0 + ((double)x / (double)width) * (ranges.mapx1 - ranges.mapx0)) * 3;
                ny = (ranges.mapy0 + ((double)y / (double)height) * (ranges.mapy1 - ranges.mapy0)) * 3;

                if (combinedTerrain.Get(nx, ny) > threshold)
                {
                    fractalCoords.Add(new Vector3Int(x, height - y, 0));
                }
            }
        }

        return fractalCoords;
    }
}
```

and i attached different colored square sprites for each of those gameobjects, and saved them as a prefab. Once i had that prefab, i attached that to the `fractalLayers` list in my previous script to generate ores. And although it runs fine on a lower scale, I cant run it on a larger scale. And since there's no cure-all for making code run faster (aside from refactoring, which i don't know how to do), and i probably could've made parts of my code more efficient since I'm a novice, i would really like some insight from the eyes of a professional on how to make my code run better. I know i didn't explain everything about my project but its really just a bare-bones project those are the only scripts and unique parts about it, you can just infer what i did and fill in the blanks. Any help is appreciated. And if you could give me the extra push along with some information on the subject, I would love to have some videos recommended along with your insight to guide me along this process, since i am more of a visual learner. Thank you! =)

[(For reference, it took me about 4 minutes to build this, with the settings shown here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoREM.png)

Comment: There are a great number of ways I could optimize this just glancing over it.  That said, I would very much suggest using performance and memory profilers.  This will show you actual metrics and from there you can get more pointed solutions, and questions.

Comment: A [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will make your question more clear. Especially there is a bunch of code. I'll suggest to profile your cost time by `StopWatch`, or if you need precision less than 15 ms, use [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789474/how-to-get-ticks-from-queryperformancecounter-in-c)

Comment: It seems as though Minimum Reproducible Examples are for re-creating a problem with an entirely different set of code. I can see how this would be usable, and i would love to try to make one for you, but sadly I cant tell you what is exactly making it so slow. I wonder why too. If you could give me an idea I would love to make what you're asking for though if it means more input!

Comment: @TryingMyBest You may start from studying how to use `StopWatch`. Check your every for loop time cost. Until you find the loops are costing time, you may post a Minimum Reproducible Examples for your loop.

Comment: And if i managed to shorten one of my loops, do you think it is solely my loops that are the cause of the slowness or is there something inherent in the noise generation method that i used? If not, are there other practices that can further improve code performance, like refactoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently my word generation method was fine, just the loop I was using to smoothen the terrain took too long.