# QueryPerformanceCounter usage in a C++ Windows form application

Tags: c++, performance, time, timer, performancecounter

I'm trying to use the QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency timers in order to have a high resolution timestamp in my Windows Form GUI (Visual C++). The problem in my side that I do not know the exact way to use it within a Form.

The example, what I've found is clearly describes the StartCounter() and GetCounter() but I'm wondering, how to call it with a button_Click callback function in MyForm.h

The goal would be to send periodic messages after a button press in the GUI.

Can you please support me in this question? Thanks!

```
    double PCFreq = 0.0;
__int64 CounterStart = 0;
double vartest = 0;

void StartCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    //if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))

        PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart);

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
}
double GetCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return double(li.QuadPart - CounterStart) / PCFreq;
}
```

Comment: If you find the low level API troublesome you could use one of the standard clocks in C++, for example [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get ticks from QueryPerformanceCounter in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789474/how-to-get-ticks-from-queryperformancecounter-in-c)

Comment: *"the goal would be to send periodic messages after a button press in the GUI."* - then why are you polling for the time instead of using an appropriate timer class or the SetTimer API to post a message to wake you every X milliseconds?   Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in my comments, if the goal is to do something periodically on the main thread of a forms application, you want to use a Timer class in .NET or the Win32 SetTimer function to schedule a callback to occur at a given interval.

QueryPerformanceCounter is probably way more precise than you'll ever need. Instead, use [GetTickCount64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount64) to get a millisecond counter of system time.

```
ULONGLONG CounterStart = 0;

void StartCounter()
{
    CounterStart = GetTickCount64();
}

double GetCounter()
{
    ULONGLONG currentTime = GetTickCount64();
    ULONGLONG diff = currentTime - CounterStart;
    return (diff / 1000.0);  // convert milliseconds to seconds as a double
}
```